# Recursively selecting top most recursion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, recursion

I have a table which holds purely the relations between groups for an app that can have an infinite amount of sub groups.

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_groups_group_rel` (
  `id_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('shop','group') NOT NULL
);
```

Type "shop" basically means its top most.

Now I need to be able to get the top most group for ANY group I might be parsing in. I've looked into MySQL's LOOP syntax but I can't figure out how to mix this with actual queries on the database.

Can anyone give me a hint as to how I might be able to recursively select the parent group until I am at the top most group?

I know that doing this can be risky seeing as there can be infinite amount of subgroups but in practice this will never be more than 2 or 3 subgroups and I can easily impose a hard limit on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with a hard limit you could just use joins.

```
SELECT id_group,
COALESCE(p4.id_group, p3.id_group, p2.id_group, p1.id_group, g.id_group) 
  as top_id_group
FROM shop_groups_group_rel g
LEFT JOIN shop_groups_group_rel p1 ON p1.id_group = g.id_parent
LEFT JOIN shop_groups_group_rel p2 ON p2.id_group = p1.id_parent
LEFT JOIN shop_groups_group_rel p3 ON p3.id_group = p2.id_parent
LEFT JOIN shop_groups_group_rel p4 ON p4.id_group = p3.id_parent
```

It's obviously not recursive so you can't go on indefinitely but you can add as many joins as you would reasonably expect in your data set.  It's not terribly fast but it will at least short circuit in that once you reach the top parent it will basically skip the rest of the joins.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's indeed something I can do, didn't even consider that. I still would love to know if it's possible to do this in a LOOP though. But for now your solution will do the trick, there should never be more than 3 / 4 sub groups.

Comment: With MySQL you can only do the "loop" in a stored procedure as it does not support recursive queries (unlike e.g. PostgreSQL or Firebird).